# Select distinct values from 3 columns into 1

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I'm currently working with a (MySQL) database wich has a table with 3 columns containing INT values.
Each column may have NULL and repeated values, as such:

[image]

I'd like to know if it's posssible to, in 1 query, select all distinct values from each column and merge them into 1 resulting column; in this example something like:

```
col
-----
 1
 30
 40
 60
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use union

```
select * from (
select col1 as col from table
union 
select col2 as col from table
union
select col3 as col from table
) t where col is not null
order by col
```

If you have indexed your columns then you can use separate where clauses for each 3 queries in order to best utilize your index

Comment: Worked as expected! Thank you for your time.